# Multicolor bar chart with scroll

Tags: android, bar-chart, charts4j

I am working on an Android application. In my app I have to show a bar chart with multiple color So I used charts4j library. I used the code from the following link [charts4j example](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/BarChartExample.java#51).

now problem is I can show only fixed bars only if the number of bars exceeds the screen I couldn't scroll to view the remaining bars.Here is my screenshot.
[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjSk8.png)

the following is the code I used to generate bar chart.

```
 public static String getBarChartUrl()
{
    BarChartPlot team1 = Plots.newBarChartPlot( Data.newData( 25, 43, 12, 30,32,25, 43, 12, 30,32,25,25, 43, 12, 30,32,25 ), BLUEVIOLET, "Team A" );
    BarChartPlot team2 = Plots.newBarChartPlot( Data.newData( 8, 35, 11, 5,9,25, 35, 11, 5,9,25,25, 43, 12, 30,32,25 ), ORANGERED, "Team B" );
    BarChartPlot team3 = Plots.newBarChartPlot( Data.newData( 10, 20, 30, 30 ,15,32, 20, 30, 30 ,15,32,25, 43, 12, 30,32,25), LIMEGREEN, "Team C" );

    // Instantiating chart.
    BarChart chart = GCharts.newBarChart( team1, team2, team3 );

    // Defining axis info and styles
    AxisStyle axisStyle = AxisStyle.newAxisStyle( BLACK, 13, AxisTextAlignment.CENTER );
    AxisLabels score = AxisLabelsFactory.newAxisLabels( "Score", 50.0 );
    score.setAxisStyle( axisStyle );
    AxisLabels year = AxisLabelsFactory.newAxisLabels( "Year", 50.0 );
    year.setAxisStyle( axisStyle );

    // Adding axis info to chart.
    chart.addXAxisLabels( AxisLabelsFactory.newAxisLabels( "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018" ) );
    chart.addYAxisLabels( AxisLabelsFactory.newNumericRangeAxisLabels( 0, 100 ) );
    chart.addYAxisLabels( score );
    chart.addXAxisLabels( year );

    chart.setSize( 600, 450 );
    chart.setBarWidth( 50 );
    chart.setSpaceWithinGroupsOfBars( 20 );
    chart.setDataStacked( true );
    chart.setTitle( "Team Scores", BLACK, 16 );
    chart.setGrid( 100, 10, 3, 2 );
    chart.setBackgroundFill( Fills.newSolidFill( ALICEBLUE ) );
    LinearGradientFill fill = Fills.newLinearGradientFill( 0, LAVENDER, 100 );
    fill.addColorAndOffset( WHITE, 0 );
    chart.setAreaFill( fill );
    String url = chart.toURLString();
    return normalize( url );
}
```

My problems are

1)As per the data the graph must show the 17 bars but it is showing 8 bars only[year from 2002 to 2018 now its showing up to 2009 only].How can I view the remaining bars by horizontal scroll.

2)If the number of bars is less then I can view the labels[ represent each color to which data].please have a look on the below image[image: bar chart with label]

If the number of is more then I cant view the label.See the first iamge.

3) I want to know is there any way to give separate background color for  border. I mean for the scores and years

Please help me to find a solution

Comment: The link you specified is not working

Comment: @amalBit...sorry.now check the link

Comment: You can change your main layout into a horizontal scrollview

Comment: +1 for pointing out the issue...

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken  `charts4j` uses `WebView` for displaying charts.

So, add this line for your `WebView`

```
yourWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

This will give zooming functionality for `WebView` ,

Hope this helps...

Comment: @CRUSADER.. got zoom..But I cant view the all bars..I need a horizontal scroll to see the entire bars.

Comment: Can you post the url you get from charts4j that you use to display in Webview

Comment: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=600x500&chbh=50,20,8&chxt=y,y,x,x&chts=000000,16&chtt=Team+Scores&chxp=1,50.0|3,50.0&chg=100.0,10.0,3,2&chco=8A2BE2,FF4500,32CD32&chdl=Team+A|Team+B|Team+C&chxs=1,000000,13,0|3,000000,13,0&chxr=0,0.0,100.0|1,0.0,100.0|3,0.0,100.0&chf=bg,s,F0F8FF|c,lg,0,E6E6FA,1.0,FFFFFF,0.0&chxl=1:|Score|2:|2002|2003|2004|2005|2006|2007|2008|2009|2010|2011|2012|2013|2014|2015|2016|2017|2018|3:|Year&chd=e:QAbhHrTNUeQAbhHrTNUeQAQAbhHrTNUeQA,FIWZHCDNFxQAWZHCDNFxQAQAbhHrTNUeQA,GaMzTNTNJmUeMzTNTNJmUeQAbhHrTNUeQA

Comment: @ CRUSADER...see my url on above comment

Comment: @sarath, Now I got your point from link provided above. Yes, the chart did return partial data because the data requested was too big.. Well this indeed is among the defects of charts4j. you can report this prob directly to google through this [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list)..

Comment: @sarath, thiere was an option of varing the chart size, but there is limit up there as well, they have set maximum size of 300000 pixels...

Comment: @ CRUSADER...Hi is there any other charts available to fix my issue?

Comment: Well there are may options, you have to check which fits yous best. Try [this](http://androidplot.com/) or [this](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html) or even [this](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/)

Comment: @ CRUSADER ..Can Show multiciolor bar chart using afreechart?..I got some example of afreechart..but that all for multi color group bar chart like your second link.. ANd the afreechart also dont have the horizontal scroll option they just reduce the width of the bar...Isn't it?

Comment: yes, you are right.. That's why I suggested to go through as many options for which matches your specific requirements i.e. more bar data... If u r comfortable with afreechart.. go for it...